# How to make my NoSQL model structure flatter than what it is (Firebase Realtime Database)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm trying to model a database structure to retrieve restaurants within a specific city.

*For example:*
When a user accepts to share his/her location, I'm using the address object of the user to retrieve restaurants within that specific location. I'm trying to retrieve only restaurants for that specific city and not restaurants in a different country because it will only take more time and that data is not necessary for the user, in other words it only increases time complexity.

I'm currently using Firebase realtime database which is a NoSQL JSON database.
**What will be the best practice to develop such a structure?**

So far, I thought about creating such a structure, e.g:

Countries

```
--> France = {Paris, Lyon, Nantes},   
-->Australia = {Sydney, Melbourne},   
-->India = {Mumbai, New Delhi},   
-->Canada = {Toronto, Ottawa, Montreal, Victoria},   
-->Et cetera
```

Within each city I will have my list of restaurants
**For example:**

```
Paris --> {Le ciel de paris, le cinq, Savoy}.
```

This looks a little bit nested to me, I'm trying to follow [Firebase Realtime Database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) but I cannot think of any other way to flatten my data.

**Question:**
Is there a way to make my model structure more flatten so retrieving the data won't be a hassle?

*I'm a noSQL newbie, and help will be appreciate it *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation for your database structure is to have a single node in which you can add all the cities under the corresponding country and should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   --- countries
         |
         --- France
               |
               --- restaurantIdOne
               |      |
               |      --- city: "Paris"
               |      |
               |      --- //other restaurant details
               |
               --- restaurantIdTwo
                      |
                      --- city: "Lyon"
                      |
                      --- //other restaurant details
```

Using this database structure, you can easley query your database to get all the restaruants that belong to a specific country/city. For example, let's say you want to to get all the restaruants in France/Paris. To achieve this, you need to use a query that looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("countries").child("France").orderByChild("city").equalTo("Paris");
```

Comment: In the documentation it says to avoid nesting and it is better to flatten data as much as possible to benefit from a faster execution in retrieving data. So for example, if we want to retrieve a restaurant in a specific city, we will have to parse through all countries even though we KNOW that the user is currently located in a specific location X, hence a country X.

Comment: Firebase documentation doesn't say to flatten the data as much as possible, it just recommends this practice but only when is needed. Don't flatten the data just for the sake of having database flatten. Remember Firebase allows you to have 32 childrens in depth. However, knowing this, I have recommended you this database schema which is already flatten. You only have restaurant objects under two fixed nodes. That's it! There is no need to have three nodes which involes you to create three nested queries, why? You can use only one that solves your entire problem, right?

Comment: Depth is not a factor that affects speed on a technical level. Firebase can as quickly look up a node at level 32 as it can at level 1. Please also see my answer from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45482400/structuring-firebase-data)**, for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is fine, but it depends on how many restaurants and restaurant data you are storing. For example, if you're UI first displays a list of restaurants and then displays a bunch of metadata after viewing a restaurant, you may want something like this:

```
{
  restaurants: {
    country1: {
      city1: {
        restaurant1: {
          title: 
          cuisine:
        },
        restaurant2: {
          title:
          cuisine:
        }
      }
    }
  }
  restaurantData: {
    restaurant1: {
      comments: {
        ...
      }
      pictures: {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That way, when your UI displays a list of restaurants, you don't have to download tons of extra data that may not be needed.

Comment: Users will have the ability to create restaurants if they would like to. Which means that the pool of restaurants within a city will grow continuously, that's why I'm trying to flatten data as much as possible.